# Trying to POST to a SharePoint List: 'SP' is undefined ReferenceError: 'SP' is undefined

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write a JS function that sends a POST request to a SharePoint List to add new List items to that List. I have done this in the past using SP.ClientContext and would like to continue to do so, as this is the only way I know of to send multiple insert requests in a batch. Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Inserts new items to a List
 * 
 * @params string siteUrl
 * @params object[] newListItems
 * @params string listName
 * @params string[] listItemFields
 * 
 * @returns bool
**/
function insertListItems(siteUrl, newListItems, listName, listItemFields) {  
    if(newListItems.length == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var olist = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName); 

    // Get SP list   
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();

    for(var i = 0; i < newListItems.length; i++) {
        oListItem = olist.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

        for(var j = 0; j < listItemFields.length; j++) {
            oListItem.set_item(listItemFields[j], newListItems[i][listItemFields[j]]);
        }

        oListItem.update();
    }

    clientContext.load(oListItem); 
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        this.successHandler("Items inserted to " + listName), 
        this.errorHandler()
    );  
}
```

I have moved this code to a new SP site, but now when I attempt to run the function I get "jQuery.Deferred exception: 'SP' is undefined ReferenceError: 'SP' is undefined" in my console. One potential issue is that this code was originally written in a SP site where the List was within the same site. Now I am working in a subsite of the SP site and the List is in a different subsite of the same SP site (not my call :/). Another potential issue is that before this was all added to a script tag within html that was embedded in the site. Now I have moved the JS out of that html file and am referring to it with an external script tag, though none of the other scripts I am using in the html file have changed.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your master page has reference to below to file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js" ></script>
```

Also use network tab to check if this 2 files are being requested and downloaded without error.

run your code under this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {

 //write code here to get siteurl, newlistems, listname etc...the function which you are using to call below function.
 insertListItems(siteUrl, newListItems, listName, listItemFields) 

});


});
```

Comment: I've added the code you recommended, but now I'm getting the same error when it calls SP.SOD.executeFunc(). I'm not sure how this was supposed to work, since it calls SP in order to fix an error that SP isn't defined.

Comment: In that case check-in your master page is there is reference to SP.js and sp.runtime.js.....  I assumed that your code is getting executed before SP.js is loaded.

Comment: Can you explain what that reference would look like? I don't believe I'm explicitly referencing SP.js in my html currently. I didn't need to when I wrote the code in the previous SP site.

Comment: Edited answer what reference would look like...!!

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I've added the references you mentioned. But now the error I'm  seeing is "SCRIPT5009: 'Type' is undefined", in reference to a line in SP.js. I've already included "<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.5.2/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>" above the reference to SP.js, but that doesn't seem to be helping.